# "Interpretation" versus "judgement" versus "assertion"?

Tags: terminology, first-order-logic

I believe "assertion" and "judgment" mean the same thing (at least according to Per Martin Lof). I understand that they are meta statements (above that of say formal propositions). How, if at all, do these meanings differ from that of "interpretation", which is also on top of a proposition?

Comment: See [Judgment (mathematical logic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judgment_(mathematical_logic)): "In mathematical logic, a judgment or assertion is a statement or enunciation in the metalanguage. For example, typical judgments in first-order logic would be that a string is a well-formed formula, or that a proposition is true."

Comment: An [Interprettaion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic)) is a way to assign "meaning to the symbols of a formal language". In a mathematical precise definition it needs a *domain* of objects and a function that maps symbols and expressions to objects and subsets of the domain.

Comment: I'm still not clear how judging a proposition true differs from interpreting as true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interpretation is a situation in which a statement can become true or false.
The claim that the statement is true in that situation is a judgement.

E.g., "$P$ means 'is even' and $a$ means '1'" is an interpretation.
"Under the interpretation where $P$ means 'is even' and $a$ means '1', the statement $P(a)$ is false" is a judgement or assertion.

There are plenty kinds of assertions other than truth under an interpretation, e.g. "$X$ is provable", "$X$ logically entails $Y$", $X$ is a formula", etc.

Comment: It took a little while to digest this, but it sounds good to me!

Answer (score 1):

In "mainstream" treatment of mathematical logic, The [Turnstile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_(symbol)#Interpretations) symbol is used in:

> $\Gamma \vdash \alpha$

to mean that formula $\alpha$ is *derivable* from the set $\Gamma$ of premises according to the rules of the *logical calculus* (aka: proof system), i.e. using logical axioms and *Modus Ponens* or e.g. [Natural Deduction](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) rules.

It derives from [Frege (1879)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/) : "...Frege's symbol came to be called the assertion sign.  Frege's notation for a judgement $\vdash A$ can then be read I know $A$ is true."

The [Double turnstile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_turnstile) symbol is used in:

> $\Gamma \vDash \alpha$

to mean that $\alpha$ is a [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Semantic_consequence) of the set $\Gamma$ of premises.

This second notion is defined using the concept of *interpretation*: the set of the interpretations that make all members of $\Gamma$ true is a subset of the set of the interpretations that make $\alpha$ true.

The two relations are very different but strictly linked: a calculus is said to be *sound* and *complete* when:

> $\Gamma \vDash \alpha \text {  iff  } \Gamma \vdash \alpha$.

In other words, the caluclus is able to derive from a set of premises all and only the logical consequences of the said premises.

If so, we are licensed to read the judgment $\Gamma \vdash \alpha$ both as "formula $\alpha$ is *derivable* from premises $\Gamma$" and as "formula $\alpha$ is true in every model of $\Gamma$".

---

Things are a little bit different with a different approach; see e.g. Per Martin-Lof's [Intuitionistic type theory (1984)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory-intuitionistic):

> [page 2] When we hold a proposition to be true, we make a *judgement*: $A$ is a proposition, "proposition $A$ is true" is a judgement.

> In particular, the premisses and conclusion of a logical inference are judgements.

And

> [page 6] a proposition is true if it has a proof, that is, if a proof of it can be given.

Comment: Thanks. I my mind there is a tension between the purely syntactic notion entailment encoded with the single turnstile and understanding it as "a judgement ⊢ [that] can then be read I know  is true". The latter, a judgment or assertion (which are roughly equivalent, according to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGUzgcLXNuk) goes beyond  mere form.

Comment: @JRC - "the purely syntactic notion encoded with the single turnstile" is usually named *derivability* and not *entailment*.