# Logical consequence (⊨ and ⊢) — A statement? A judgement? A meta-statement?

Tags: logic, terminology, first-order-logic, metalogic

I'm trying to understand the terminology used in mathematical logic and I'm confused about the distinctions between statement, proposition, judgement, claim, and meta-variants of those. In particular, I'm wondering what to call formulas that express semantic consequence ($\Gamma \vDash \varphi$) and syntactic consequence ($\Gamma \vdash \varphi$). Say that I want to prove that $$p \to q, p \vDash q$$ by appealing to the definition of $\vDash$. What is the thing I am proving? Can I simply call such a formula a statement? Or is it a statement about statements?

Comment: There's the meta-language/system you're working *in* and the formal language/system you're reasoning *about*. Both of them have statements/propositions/formulas/etc. but we can only use those words in a precisely defined sense when referring to the formal language. The meta-language can't technically refer to itself (and if it seems to, it's probably informal shorthand for something less self-referential).

Comment: I recommend that you try to understand the statement  of a classic result like the completeness theorem. I think you will find that the statement uses the logical consequence relation ($\vdash$) or the satisfaction relation ($\models$), but doesn't make meta-mathematical statements about those relations.

Comment: It is an expression of the meta-language and not a formula of the formal language. Thus, it is a statement expressing a property of the "objects": formulas, derivations, of the formal system. We may call it also a *judgment*.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3949646/interpretation-versus-judgement-versus-assertion)